# vkQueueSubmit() call includes a stageMask with VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_GEOMETRY_SHADER_BIT bit set when device does not have geometryShader feature enabled

Tags: vulkan

First of all, I'm a total newbie with Vulkan (I'm using the binding provided by LWJGL). I know I should copy/paste more code, but I don't even know what would be relevant for now (so don't hesitate to ask me some specific piece of code).

I try to make something like that :

- Use a ComputeShader to compute a buffer of pixel.
- Use vkCmdCopyBufferToImage to directly copy this array into a framebuffer image.

So, no vertex/fragment shaders for now.

I allocated a Compute Pipeline, and a FrameBuffer. I have one {Queue/CommandPool/CommandBuffer} for Computation, and one other for Rendering.

When I try to submit the graphic queue with:

```
vkQueueSubmit(graphicQueue, renderPipeline.getFrameSubmission().getSubmitInfo(imageIndex));
```

I obtain the following error message (from validation) :

```
ERROR OCCURED: Object: VK_NULL_HANDLE (Type = 0) | vkQueueSubmit() call includes a stageMask with VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_GEOMETRY_SHADER_BIT bit set when device does not have geometryShader feature enabled. The spec valid usage text states 'If the geometry shaders feature is not enabled, each element of pWaitDstStageMask must not contain VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_GEOMETRY_SHADER_BIT' (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkSubmitInfo-pWaitDstStageMask-00076)
ERROR OCCURED: Object: VK_NULL_HANDLE (Type = 0) | vkQueueSubmit() call includes a stageMask with VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TESSELLATION_CONTROL_SHADER_BIT and/or VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TESSELLATION_EVALUATION_SHADER_BIT bit(s) set when device does not have tessellationShader feature enabled. The spec valid usage text states 'If the tessellation shaders feature is not enabled, each element of pWaitDstStageMask must not contain VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TESSELLATION_CONTROL_SHADER_BIT or VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TESSELLATION_EVALUATION_SHADER_BIT' (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkSubmitInfo-pWaitDstStageMask-00077)
```

I tried to change the VkSubmitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask to different values (like VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_DRAW_INDIRECT_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COMPUTE_SHADER_BIT...) but nothing change.

So, what would be the best pWaitDstStageMask for my use case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found my problem: 
The pWaitDstStageMask must be an array with the same size than pWaitSemaphores.

I only putted 1 stage mask, for 2 semaphores.